# Flutter IOS | I can not run on the ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator

Failed to build iOS app
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/jfr/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.1.4/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4:8
FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/jfr/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.1.4/ios/Classes/messages.g.m:7:8
messages.g.m:7

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

thats pod install:
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target Runner to Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig or include the Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig in your build configuration (Flutter/Release.xcconfig).

if i run the flutter app and this is shows

i only clean the flutter and upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are encountering in Xcode indicates that the file 'Flutter/Flutter.h' could not be found. This issue commonly occurs when there are problems with the project configuration or when required dependencies are not properly set up.

To resolve this error, you can try the following steps:

1. Make sure you have the Flutter framework installed and configured
   correctly. You can verify this by running the flutter doctor command
   in your terminal. If there are any issues reported, follow the
   instructions to resolve them.
2. Check if the 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file exists in your project. It
   should be located in the 'ios/Flutter' directory. If the file is
   missing, you can try running the flutter clean command in your
   project directory and then running flutter pub get to regenerate the
   necessary files.
3. Verify that the 'url_launcher_ios' package is properly installed and
   up to date. Run the flutter pub outdated command to check for any
   outdated packages and update them using flutter pub upgrade.
4. Clean your Xcode project build folder. In Xcode, go to Product ->
   Clean Build Folder. This action will clean all intermediate build
   files and can often resolve build-related issues.
5. If none of the above steps resolve the issue, you can try deleting
   the 'Pods' folder and the 'Podfile.lock' file in the 'ios' directory
   of your project and then running flutter run again. This will force
   the reinstallation of the Cocoapods dependencies.
6. Ensure that your Xcode project has the correct target selected.
   Sometimes, if you have multiple targets or configurations, the build
   settings may not be correctly applied. Make sure the target is set
   to the appropriate version of iOS and that the necessary
   dependencies are included.

I hope these steps help you as well.